# which database to use for android app

Tags: android, database, android-intent

how can I deploy android application to receive notifications when the online database is changed?

Using a database phpmysql, how can I communicate this with my android app? Thank you all for the safe response

Comment: Are you looking for push notification, if so here is a link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Web service + GCM http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to have a look at Google Cloud Messaging, your server can push a notification to a specific device or broadcast messages to all your devices that something has happened on your server.